# Emacs c++ cannot use semantic and company-semantic to complete <string> library function

Tags: init-file, company-mode, c++, semantic

system: linux mint 18.1

Eamcs version: 25.2

semantic configuration：

`(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
(semantic-mode 1)`

create a cpp file and include vector,map std library:
[image][image]

But not work for string library:

check`semantic-dependency-system-include-path`:`("/usr/include" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/" "/usr/local/include/" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/" "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/" "/usr/include/" "/usr/include/c++/5/" "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/" "/usr/include/c++/5/backward/")`

I found a file named "string" in `/usr/include/c++/5` and it only includes some head files.

Then I found a head file `basic_string.h` from `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/` and it includes some functions for c++ string library. `semantic-dependency-system-include-path`shows that `/usr/include` was already included. How can I figure out this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on another ubuntu based distro and emacs 24.5.1. semantic version is 2.2. I do not yet have a solution. I suspect the string header itself is causing a parsing problem for semantic. It actually cannot locate the string header to jump to either (semantic-ia-fast-jump). I have triple checked system header includes. It works with other stl objects like collections etc. (semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/c++/5") (semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5") (semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/c++/5/backward") (semantic-add-system